# How to create in angular simple independent grid directive fully configured in controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to create independent grid directive in angular. Data and actions will be set in controller. Action can refer to other controllers or other action in parent controller. Both are possible.

---

Here is live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/efe4notoE1TyONH3W347?p=preview

in index.html

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div grid data="data" action-list="actionList" call="call(fun, row)"></div>
</body>
```

controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [
        {id: 1, name: 'aaa'},
        {id: 2, name: 'bbb'},
        {id: 3, name: 'ccc'}
    ];

    // actions (show, delete) have to be defined before $scope.actionList
    $scope.show = function (row) {
        alert('show: ' + row.id + ':' + row.name);
    }
    $scope.delete = function (row) {
        alert('delete: ' + row.id);
    }

    $scope.actionList = [
        { label: 'edit', href: '#/edit/{{row.id}}', title: 'to other CTRL' },
        { label: 'show', click: $scope.show, title: 'use ngClick' },
        { label: 'delete', click: $scope.delete, title: 'use ngClick' }
    ];

    // call any action in this CTRL
    $scope.call = function (fun, row) {
        fun(row);
    }

});
```

grid directive. Parameter `call` will be used to pass all action functions to controller. `hrefCompiled` compile `href` of action (e.g. `#/edit/{{row.id}}`)

```
app.directive('grid', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            actionList: '=',
            call: '&'
        },
        // 
        controller: function ($scope, $interpolate) {
            $scope.hrefCompiled = function (action, row) {
                if (action.href) {
                    return $interpolate(action.href)({row: row})
                }
                return '';
            }
        },
        templateUrl: 'grid.html'
    }
});
```

grid.html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in data[0]">{{key}}</th>
        <th>actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td>{{row.id}}</td>
        <td>{{row.name}}</td>
        <td>
            <span ng-repeat="action in actionList">
                <a href="{{hrefCompiled(action, row)}}"
                ng-click="call({fun: action.click, row: row})"
                title="{{action.title}}">{{action.label}}</a>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/efe4notoE1TyONH3W347?p=preview

**May be this is not best practice, but it works. Please help me to improve it.** Thanks.

Comment: When I attempt to edit or delete it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer or use one of those angular-table plugins: http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ or http://angulartable.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-table](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/) directive allow to liven your tables. It support sorting, filtering and pagination. Header row with titles and filters automatic generated on compilation step.

```
Examples
```

[Pagination](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1)

[Sorting](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/3)

[Filtering](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/4)

[Cell template](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/8)

[Row template](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/9)

[Params in url](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/5)

[Ajax](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/6)

[Custom template(pagination)](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/2)

[Custom filters](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/11)

[Table with checkboxes](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/10)